# Isolate objects in JAVA after the copy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two objects `A a` and `B b`:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
```

I need to copy `a` into `b` but when I set some attribute in `a`, I still the same result in `b` after the clone. For example:

```
C c = new C();
c.setName("c name");
a.setAtt1("toto");
a.setAtt2("toto");
a.setAttC(c);

BeanUtils.copyproperties(a,b);

a.setAttC(null);
```

When I display `b` I found that the `AttC` object is `null` such as the copy was processed before setting it `null` in `a`.

Would you have any idea how I can isolate the two object after the copy?

Comment: You may need some sort of delegate class, no?

Comment: It is really not clear. I would expect that `attC` in `b` would have the value before copying, i.e. `c`. You say it is `null`. This should not be the case. Either you're mistaken or I don't get what you ask.

Comment: are you sure that the name of the property of type C is the same in A and B because BeanUtils.copyproperties is based on same name properties.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and indicate what does not work and how would you like it to work.

Comment: I  found that I have to deep copy, create new instance of attC for "b" object, the "attC" also after the copy. The objects "b" and "a" have the same reference to the object "attC" so that's why when the object "a" update attC the object "b" have the same modification

Comment: The solution will be:  C c2 = new C();     c2 = a.getAttC();  and after the copy do   b.setAttC(c2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are copying properties over from a to b the reference to c remains same in both the object. You need to perform a deep copy which will clone the object c in b. Please refer to following link for details:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html#clone(T)